# Tikz-cd Crossing Over Issue

Tags: tikz-cd, syntax, syntax-checker

I'm drawing a diagram and I want one specific line to be crossed over by all others that pass by it. I'll put the picture of my diagram below for you to see what I want.

[image: Diagram]

So, the red arrow indicates where I want the crossing over to happen, I want the line between A and G to be crossed over by the lines between B and D' and between B and F'.

The black arrow idicates where I don't want any changes, I want the line between B and F' to cross under the line between D and {e}.

I have programmed this as follows:

```
\documentclass[border=20]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={dash}]
     &&  &&&  & \{e\} &  &&&  &&  \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     &&  &&&  & B'\arrow[uuuuuu, dashed, purple] & A'\arrow[uuuuuul, dashed, blue] &&&  &&  \\
    E'\arrow[uuuuuuurrrrrr, blue]\arrow[dddddrrrrrr, dashed, purple] &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  && F'\arrow[uuuuuuullllll, blue]\arrow[dddddllllll, dashed, crossing over, purple] \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     && C'\arrow[uuuuuuuuuurrrr, crossing over, blue]\arrow[ddrrrr, dashed, purple] &&&  &  & A\arrow[uuuu, dashed, blue] &&& D'\arrow[ddllll, dashed, crossing over, purple]\arrow[uuuuuuuuuullll, crossing over, blue] &&  \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
    E\arrow[uuuuu, blue]\arrow[dddddrrrrrr, blue] &&  &&&  & B\arrow[uuuuuu, dashed, purple]\arrow[uuuuuur, dashed, purple] &  &&&  && F\arrow[uuuuu, blue]\arrow[dddddllllll, blue] \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     && C\arrow[uuuuu, crossing over, blue] &&&  &  &  &&& D\arrow[uuuuu, crossing over, blue] &&  \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     &&  &&&  & G\arrow[uullll, blue]\arrow[uurrrr, blue]\arrow[uuuuu, dashed, purple]\arrow[uuuuuuur, dashed, blue] &  &&&  &&  \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You just need to draw the lines in the correct order: A-G, then (crossing over) B-D' and B-F', then (crossing over again) D'-{e}. You can use the syntax `\arrow[from=11-11, to=13-7, dashed, crossing over, purple]`, which is from D' to B. (B is in row 13, column 7). Use that code after the rest of the diagram is complete. Or you can use `alias` to name the cells (Y and Z for example) and use `from=Z`, to=Y`. But don't use U,D,L,R for names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want the `BF'` line to go over the `AG` line and under the `D'{e}` line. Here is the image:

[image]

You just need to draw the lines in the correct order: first `AG`, then (crossing over) `BD'` and `BF'`. Last (crossing over again) `D'{e}`. You can use the syntax `\arrow[from=11-11, to=13-7, dashed, crossing over, purple]`, which is from `D'` to `B`. (`B` is in row 13, column 7).

Here is the code:

```
\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={dash}]
     &&  &&&  & \{e\} &  &&&  &&  \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     &&  &&&  & B'\arrow[uuuuuu, dashed, purple] & A'\arrow[uuuuuul, dashed, blue] &&&  &&  \\
    E'\arrow[uuuuuuurrrrrr, blue]\arrow[dddddrrrrrr, dashed, purple] &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  && F'\arrow[uuuuuuullllll, blue] \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     && C'\arrow[uuuuuuuuuurrrr, crossing over, blue]\arrow[ddrrrr, dashed, purple] &&&  &  & A\arrow[uuuu, dashed, blue] &&& D' &&  \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
    E\arrow[uuuuu, blue]\arrow[dddddrrrrrr, blue] &&  &&&  & B\arrow[uuuuuu, dashed, purple]\arrow[uuuuuur, dashed, purple] &  &&&  && F\arrow[uuuuu, blue]\arrow[dddddllllll, blue] \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     && C\arrow[uuuuu, crossing over, blue] &&&  &  &  &&& D\arrow[uuuuu, crossing over, blue] &&  \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     &&  &&&  & G\arrow[uullll, blue]\arrow[uurrrr, blue]\arrow[uuuuu, dashed, purple]\arrow[uuuuuuur, dashed, blue] &  &&&  && \\
     \arrow[from=11-11, to=13-7, dashed, crossing over, purple]
     \arrow[from=8-13, to=13-7, dashed, crossing over, purple]
     \arrow[from=11-11, to=13-7, dashed, purple]
     \arrow[from=11-11, to=1-7, crossing over, blue]
\end{tikzcd}
```

Note that I drew the `D'B` arrow twice. Once crossing over, then again after `F'B` was drawn (but before `D'{e}`) so the ends of the lines at `B` don't interfere with each other.

Comment: I appreciate your solution

Comment: That's exactly what I was going for, I now have a deeper understanding of the tikz-cd syntax. Thank you very very much!!

Answer (score 4):

Does this MWE meet the requirement of your question?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=20]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={dash}]
     &&  &&&  & \{e\} &  &&&  &&  \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     &&  &&&  & B'\arrow[uuuuuu, dashed, purple] & A'\arrow[uuuuuul, dashed, blue] &&&  &&  \\
    E'\arrow[uuuuuuurrrrrr, blue]\arrow[dddddrrrrrr, dashed, purple] &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  && F'\arrow[uuuuuuullllll, blue]\arrow[dddddllllll, dashed, crossing over, purple] \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     && C'\arrow[uuuuuuuuuurrrr, crossing over, blue]\arrow[ddrrrr, dashed, purple] &&&  &  & A\arrow[uuuu, dashed, blue] &&& D'\arrow[ddllll, dashed, crossing over, purple]\arrow[uuuuuuuuuullll, crossing over, blue] &&  \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
    E\arrow[uuuuu, blue]\arrow[dddddrrrrrr, blue] &&  &&&  & B\arrow[uuuuuu, dashed, purple]\arrow[uuuuuur, dashed, purple] &  &&&  && F\arrow[uuuuu, blue]\arrow[dddddllllll, blue] \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     && C\arrow[uuuuu, crossing over, blue] &&&  &  &  &&& D\arrow[uuuuu, crossing over, blue] &&  \\
     &&  &&&  &  &  &&&  &&  \\
     &&  &&&  & G\arrow[uullll,blue]\arrow[uurrrr, blue]\arrow[uuuuu, dashed, purple]\arrow[uuuuuuur, crossing over, dashed, blue] &  &&&  &&  \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It didn't, the blue lines were meant to be the outer parts of the diamond. But thank you very much for the effort!